# Document cannot be resolved to a type : I added a dependency of javax.xml

Tags: eclipse, exception, dom, rcp, pde

I am developing a RCP Application with its product.
When I export the product, the  application does not work with xml-dom showing some errors as below.

I added javax.xml dependency both in plug-in project and the product configuration.
I am using eclipse 2021-09 and jdk 17.
and I removed java.xml in Module Dependencies, Java Build Path for the plug-in project since there were some error with "import  javax.xml.*" saying that ***  is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml.

I cleaned the project several time and then exported the product again.
It is working well when I run it from eclipse but does not work with a exported application.
I would appreciate for some help.

```
   org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Document cannot be resolved to a type
    DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be resolved
    NodeList cannot be resolved to a type
)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4893)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4808)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4029)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3629)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problems` means the code did not compile properly. How are you building the RCP? With Tycho? What do the build logs say?

Comment: I have a .target file of several update-sites and it works well when I run it from eclipse. There is no error in compile time. The log I attached here is all. I don't know why it is not working with a exported exe file.

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problems` message can only mean there **are** compilation problems. Again how are you building the RCP? If you are using the old (deprecated) Export Eclipse product the build logs are hidden away. The log you show is not the build log.

Comment: oh I found the log.  It says as below: 
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

But I've already removed java.xml module dependency  for this error.